# c++ const int input

Tags: c++, input, int, constants

I would like to give an array an length x.
The x is user input. but the problem is that the x must be const.

this is the code i have:

```
int *length = 0;
cin >> (*length);
const int arraylength = const_cast<int>(*length);
int l[arraylength];
```

Comment: Note you are deferencing a null pointer.

Comment: The size of an array does not only need to be const, it must be a *constant expression*, which means *known at **compile** time*. You should ask about the problem and not the solution, what is it that you really need done?

Comment: Not that it helps with the problem, but you can deal with the null-dereference bug simply by removing all the stars from your code.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot allocate a stack-based array with dynamic length in C++ (you can in C) -- the length needs to be compile-time constant.  You need to dynamically allocate the array (or use `std::vector<>`)

```
int* l = new int[arrayLength];
// use l as you did before
delete[] l; // when you no longer need to access its contents
```

Also, you declare a pointer `length`, but it is initialized to `NULL`, which means you cannot dereference it (your `cin >> (*length);` will fail at runtime)

*Note*: since you are using C++ it would be better to use `std::vector<int>` instead of a raw array -- you get the benefit of dynamic resizing if necessary and possible bounds checking (when using its `at()` member function), also no need to delete it as it uses the RAII idiom to clean up the allocated memory once its lifetime is over (which also provides memory leak protection in the face of exceptions).

Comment: It would be desirable to use `std::vector`, given that it deals with memory deallocation for you.

Comment: @Rook - thx.  I hinted at the use of vector, but you are correct -- I've extended the answer to include its benefits

Answer (score 3):

C++ doesn't support VLA's (variable length arrays). Although `const`, your `int` is not fixed at compile-time.

Alternatives:

```
std::vector<int> l(arraylength);
```

or

```
int* l = new int[arraylength];
//...
delete[] l;
```